# What is the standard CSS container size in 2018?

Tags: css, user-interface, responsive-design

When designing a responsive layout, what size is the standard for using a `max-width` container in 2018? Currently I am using **1140px** to fit the standard screen size of **1366px**.

Comment: I'd say still 1200px.

Comment: Facebook: 1012px | Twitter: 1190px | SO: 1090px | Though I may not know why, there's a reason these are similar and I'm happy to follow in blind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say use the bootstrap container sizes, as they are used pretty often and are quite the average below web development.

These are the sizes:

> xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
>
> sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
>
> md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
>
> lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

So yes, I'd use 1200px as your desktop container size.

Answer (score 6):

### UPDATE 2022

here are my latest breakpoint/container recommendations based on today's global usage statistics:

```
$breakpoints: (
    xs: 0, 
    sm: 600px, // mobile landscape, tablet (portrait)
    md: 1024px, // chromebooks, ipad pro (portrait), tablet (landscape)
    lg: 1600px, // most laptops and desktops
    xl: 2048px // 2k and up
);

$container-max-width: (
    xs: 480px, 
    sm: 960px,
    md: 1280px, 
    lg: 1920px,
    xl: 3840px
);
```

### PREVIOUS ANSWER

Based on usage statistics most common desktop resolutions are 1366 and 1920.

See usage stats: https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats

As such, I find that Bootstrap default breakpoints are too small and redefine containers as below.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 768px,
    md: 992px,
    lg: 1366px,
    xl: 1920px
);

$container-max-widths: (
    sm: 720px,
    md: 960px,
    lg: 1280px,
    xl: 1840px
);
```

EDIT: After further reflection these container max-widths are more proportional to the screen widths. This deviates more drastically from Bootstrap defaults, however.

```
$container-max-widths: (
    sm: 720px,
    md: 930px,
    lg: 1280px,
    xl: 1800px
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the material breakpoints:

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/responsive-ui.html

They use a variety of  columns and breakpoints:

< 480 / 4 cols / xsmall 
481 - 600 / 8 cols / xsmall 
601 - 840 / 8 cols / small 
841 - 960 / 12 cols / small 
961 - 1280 / 12 cols / medium 
1281 - 1440 / 12 cols / large 
1441 - 1600 / 12 cols / large 
1601 - 1920 / 12 cols / large (HD desktops) 
> 1920 / 12 cols / large (Retina desktops)

[Adaptive breakpoints in Material Design [img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWuXU.png)